# Excel, ODBC - desired database not listed

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql-server, sql, odbc

When I attempt to create an ODBC to a server (named DARKHELMET for all you spaceballs fans out there) it doesn't show in the list of available data sources.

..but it does show up under data source settings and it does show up in SSMS, so I know the PC can see the server\database I want to access.

I think the issue has to do with the face that this computer was configured on one domain, and then switched to another (at two different facilities).  The data sources listed under my ODBC connection data list are from the first domain, at the first facility, in a different state than the PC is currently on.

How do I get Excel to see the data sources on the network & domain the PC is currently on?

Also, I'm remoting into this PC from location & domain 1, but that doesn't seem to have anyting to do with it.

Comment: The datasource will need to be defined in ODBC admin where you can also test if they connect properly. It also matters if it is defined under the 32-bit or 64-bit ODBC admin. The connection must match the “bitness” of excel.

Comment: @Appleoddity I was able to get the connection added under the System DSN tab in ODBC admin on one of my PCs and it showed up in Excel as it should.  Then I tried doing it on another (the server at this location).  I added it in the ODBC admin (SQL Server driver) in the same place and tested the connection.  All was well, but it doesn't show up in Excel.  Any ideas?  I don't see a place to match bitness.

Comment: If I remember right, look for odbcad32.exe. Under windows\syswow64 it will be 32-bit version. Under windows\system32 it is 64-bit version.